# What is "IIS 7 Recommended Configuration" in Web Platform Installer 3.0?

Tags: iis-7, web-platform-installer

Just installed the new IIS Express today and saw that the Web Platform Installer also has the option to install "IIS 7 Recommended Configuration".
But I couldn't actually figure out anywhere what it does?

Anyone using it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

quote [site](http://forums.iis.net/t/1174703.aspx)

> The IIS 7 Recommended Configuration in
>   WebPI v3 is the equivilent of the IIS
>   7 components that were installed
>   automatically in WebPI v2 when you
>   installed an application.
>
> For example, in WebPI v2 and on a
>   clean Win7 machine, if you selected to
>   install DotNetNuke, WebPI would
>   automatically bring along a set of IIS
>   components so your application would
>   function.
>
> WebPI v3 does the same thing, but now
>   we've added an entry to allow you to
>   easily install our recommended set of
>   IIS7 components without installing an
>   application
>
> For reference, here is the list of
>   components
>
> - Static Content
> - Default Document
> - Directory Browse
> - HTTP Errors
> - HTTP Logging
> - Logging Libraries
> - Request Monitor
> - Request Filtering
> - HTTP Static Compression
> - Management Console
> - ASP NET
> - NetFX Extensibility
> - ISAPI Filter
> - ISAPI Extensions

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But basically if you have a running website, you don't really need this. The title sounded a little like it would for example help to make your IIS more secure or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, obviously "default components" or something would make more sense. The Web platform Installer's value would be drastically increased if they simply made the above help easily accessible in a seperate pane, or at least by right-clicking on the item.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be from the Chris Sfanos post here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1174703.aspx

But it doesn't really say what it improves over what IIS 7 already has.

Comment: It does not improve anything. It doesn't even install any new bits from the net. This entry in Web PI is just to trigger recommended configuration of IIS 7.