# What DOCtype loads Google fonts in IE9?

Tags: html, fonts, doctype

Using the google [webfont loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader%22) the font shows in IE9, but when I declare at DOCtype at the start

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

also

!DOCTYPE html 
breaks it

the font no longer loads. Leaving it out breaks the auto margins. 
Nothing so far as worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ie9 doctype and fonts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124531/ie9-doctype-and-fonts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is all I ever use anymore. It loads the fonts just fine for me.

Should it fail, add this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

And should that also fail, check the F12 Developer Tools console for error messages.

Comment: Thank you, F12 gave the answer. The fonts couldn't be loaded in IE 9 when  I ran the site locally on the machine. It worked on upload.