# internet explorer font face ssl

Tags: css, iis-7

The fonts for my site are working fine in all browsers using http. However when I change to https the fonts don't work in IE8 and below, works correctly in ie9.

Using IE, when I type the path to the .eot file using http, I get the option to download the file, but when I use https, it says it can't be found.

I'm using a self assigned certificate. iis 7.5 .net 4.0, umbraco 4.7.0 cms, client dependency framework (I have tried with client dependency framework removed, still didn't work).

```
<style type="text/css">    
@font-face {
                font-family: 'GGX88UltraLight';
                src: url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.eot');
                src: url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                     url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                     url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                     url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.svg#webfontU6kiGgEl') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

web config values that might be useful

```
<staticContent>
  <!-- Set expire headers to 30 days for static content-->
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
  <!-- use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html -->
  <remove fileExtension=".css" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".js" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".rss" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <remove fileExtension=".xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
  <!-- HTML5 Video mime types-->
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
  <!-- Remove default IIS mime type for .eot which is application/octet-stream -->
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" /> 
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
<httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: This appears to be some kind of server config or intranet settings issue. When I moved the site up to the staging server, the fonts worked fine.

Comment: What helped me was, also unsetting Vary in the .htaccess
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https)

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same behaviour using spring-boot:
the solution I found was to

**- Hide  Pragma and Cache-Control returned headers to the browser:**

Spring-boot is responding with specific Cache-Control and Pragma HTTP headers.

```
Cache-Control :"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
Pragma :"no-cache"
```

Internet explorer (IE11 in my case) is not able to load fonts with those headers.
I believe its a bug and we have to cope with it.

Using nginx to proxy our spring-boot application, 
I could overcome the problem , 
hiding that headers to the browser by using the following nginx configuration commands:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name server.dns.name;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.dns.name.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.dns.name.key;

        location / {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;

            #IE specific tweak for fonts not to be ignored:
            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            proxy_hide_header Pragma; 
            #END IE specific tweak for fonts not to be ignored
        }
}
```

Comment: I suffered from the same issue. In my application the issue was introduced with Spring Security, which by defaults sets these no-cache headers. This can be disabled by setting `<security:headers defaults-disabled="true"/>` - which avoids having to use a reverse proxy and not being able to use cache headers at all.

Answer (score 2):

What if you change the order of the url sources. Like put the "svg" url on second place .. right after "embedded-opentype".

```
   @font-face {
                font-family: 'GGX88UltraLight';
                src: url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.eot');
                src: url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                     url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.svg#webfontU6kiGgEl') format('svg'),
                     url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                     url('/css/type/ggx88_ul-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https sites uses some SSL certificates. How ever you have to place trust on those. 
For more details how to put trust manually please visit https://serverfault.com/questions/176242/how-to-manually-trust-an-ssl-certificate-to-a-development-server