# @font-face Not Working In Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

So, I have 3 font files which include eot, woff and ttf. All of them are imported in the css by using the code below, however, the font does not show up on IE but does on Chrome and Firefox.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'myriadpro';
src: url('myriadpro-regular.eot');
src: url('myriadpro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('myriadpro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('myriadpro-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Any idea on how to get this working because I have no idea on how to get this working?

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725040/font-face-is-not-working-on-ie-browser

Comment: if you use WOFF, don't also use ttf - WOFF is a byte-for-byte wrapper around real ttf/otf fonts, and every browser that supports ttf/otf also supports WOFF, so also having ttf/otf fallback mostly just wastes diskspace: users will never hit it. That said, Are you targetting IE8 and below? If not, don't use `eot`, because it's an obsolete format that existed for IE4 through IE8. IE9 and on support WOFF, so realistically, you just need WOFF without any crazy fallback rules. That said: Myriad is a **really really licensed font** and you absolutely don't have the right to serve it as a webfont.