# font-awesome icons not showing in IE9 served by nodejs

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer-9, font-awesome

We are running a node application using font-awesome and in IE9 the icons do not show up.

If we use the CDN the icons show up fine, but we cannot rely on external resources.

We are using 4.2 and http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"

Anyone seen issues with this before? Any mime type issues with node or something?

Icons work well in all other browsers, just IE9 doesn't work.

Thank-you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments by tjdett in this post: [@font-face EOT not loading over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https)

I was able to find out about this bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815313

So, needed to remove Cache-control: no-cache from responses and icons started working again in IE9