# IE11 web fonts https status 200 but not loading

Tags: https, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome, webfonts

I'm having an issue where web fonts are not loading over HTTPS in a specific version of IE11.  I've done extensive searching and have found some solutions where various headers are unset or their values are changed, but none of those solutions are valid in my situation as I've spent many hours of the last two days trying various suggestions.

To rule out my website/server configuration as the issue I tried several other sites that operate over HTTPS that use web fonts (FontAwesome specifically) and the result was the same.  Below is a screenshot from https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ showing what this page looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLZCC.jpg

Note that the font loads with a 200 but that it only 487 bytes.  The same happens for .woff fonts as well.

I was both surprised and relieved to see this error on the Font-Awesome page, which indicates this may not be something specific we are doing wrong.

I'm only getting this error in a very specific version of IE11 on Windows 8.  The full IE version number is: 11.0.9600.18036.

I've been unable to find any reports of this or any workarounds so at this point I'm at a loss what to look for next.  Is this an IE 11 bug as far as loading fonts or something specific I can correct at the website/server level.

Answer (score 0):

Font loading in IE can be nasty, we also had the issue with some IE 11 versions others worked well. We are using the material icon fonts. We even had the issue that the first side load was ok the woff file had been loaded as expected but after a refresh F5. IE showed 200 OK in the http request to get the woff file but there was no content shown in dev tools and the icons where missing.

It seems to be a IE https caching issue. For us it worked to remove following http response headers:

```
 Cache-Control, Vary
```

[You can find more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https)