# css font-face not working in IE

Tags: font-face

`@font-face{
    font-family: gotham;
    src: url('../fonts/Gotham-Light.otf');
}`
I have included font named as Gotham in my css file.Its working in mozilla and all other browsers but not in IE9.

Comment: Your question is not very informative.... Is your issue related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587956/make-adobe-fonts-work-with-css3-font-face-in-ie9 ?

Comment: @font-face requires several different font formats (as supported by different browsers) ; you can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator for instance to generate the different files.

Comment: @ramshinde1992: See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

See [**The New Bbulletproof Fontface Syntax**](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

```
    @font-face {

        font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
        src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
             url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
             url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
             url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

**How it works?**

> Internet Explorer <9 has a bug in the parser for the src attribute. If you include more than one font format in the src, IE fails to load it and reports a 404 error. The reason is that IE attempts to load as a file everything between the opening parenthesis all the way to the very last closing parenthesis. To deal with that wrong behavior, you merely declare the EOT first and append a single question mark. The question mark fools IE into thinking the rest of the string is a query string and loads just the EOT file. The other browsers follow the spec and select the format they need based on the src cascade and the format hint.

**Browser compatibility:**

> Safari 5.03, IE 6-9, Firefox 3.6-4, Chrome 8, iOS 3.2-4.2, Android 2.2-2.3, Opera 11

To generate your font-kit you should use [**fontsquirrel**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).