# Fonts WILL NOT render in IE

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, internet-explorer, font-face

URL is http://arethebaronsplaying.com/

If someone can solve this for me I'll deliver something worth their while...seriously.

I cannot get my fonts to render in IE 10 or 11 in my rails app. I get the following error in IE:

```
"CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable."
```

I don't care about earlier than 10. I've tried everything people have already suggested.

I've used the font squirrel font generator, I've added a `.htaccess' file to my root with the following inside of it:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

I've added a meta tag to my `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

I'm stuck. Here's my css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'hamilton20';
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-720-webfont.eot');
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-720-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-720-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-720-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-720-webfont.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-720-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Scotch, anyone?

Comment: I think you might need to move the fonts to the same folder the css is in. I had to do that on a website I was working on.

Comment: Have you obtained the correct license to embed the font?

Comment: @howlin The 'fonts' directory is inside the stylesheets directory where the css is stored.

Comment: @Alohci It works correctly on every other browser. Could I have to attach a license for internet explorer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587956/make-adobe-fonts-work-with-css3-font-face-in-ie9

Comment: Where did you get the fonts? Did you buy them or are they open source?

Comment: I bought them. https://www.p22.com/hwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nifty program that can be run from the command prompt to correct this error in IE9.  Be aware however, as stated on the publishers download page:

Changing the embedding value does not give you license to distribute the fonts. You should only change this setting if you are the font creator, or something like that. Use at your own risk.

[embed](http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/)

You need a 32 bit windows box (i.e. fossil) to run the program. I have access to one. I can do it for you if you want to try it.

You should contact p22 and ask them how to solve the permission issues.

Comment: I would love for you to try and solve it. I'd really appreciate that. I talked to p22 and they didn't tell me how to solve the permissions but I have a written license from them allowing me to use the site for viewing on a website. Can I email you the font files?

Comment: Send me an email to andreaslyngstad at gmail dot com. I'll give it a go.