# On Hover(content css tag) is not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, onhover, content-tag

I have used content tag in css for the on hover function as I have given an id to the image tag.But, the on Hover is not working in Firefox and IE and it's working fine in chrome. Here is the link to this : [thunderstorm999.byethost9.com](http://thunderstorm999.byethost9.com)

```css
#explore:hover {
    content: url('images/explore-hover.png');
}
#material:hover {
    content: url('images/material-hover.png');
}
#team:hover {
    content: url('images/team-hover.png');
}
#contact:hover {
    content: url('images/contact-hover.png');
}
#merchandise:hover {
    content: url('images/merchandise-hover.png');
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#"><img id="explore" src="images\explore.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img id="material" src="images\material.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img id="team" src="images\team.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img id="contact" src="images\contact.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img id="merchandise" src="images\merchandise.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `img` can't have content. So behavior of Firefox and IE is correct. Use content of `a` tag instead and set image as background.

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you please give an example using the above code?

Answer (score 1):

According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) and [w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content) the css **content** property is supposed to work only in conjunction with the **:before** and **:after** pseudo-elements. So it's better not to use it in the present case. You can do it instead like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gqhxt58j/).

```
<li id="explore">&nbsp</li>

#explore {
background: url('http://thunderstorm999.byethost9.com/images/explore.png') center no-repeat;
}

#explore:hover {
background: url('http://thunderstorm999.byethost9.com/images/explore-hover.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I checked the above fiddle but then I need to click on the menu, so they must be links. When I insert an <a> tag then the menu icons change only partially to links instead being able to click on the whole image as links. 
Any other solution or defined solution?

Comment: Also currently, when we clear the cache and then check on chrome and if we initially hover on the menu icons then there seems to be a flicker in those icons. Why is it that so ?

Comment: @user You can use the li elements themselves as links. See http://jsfiddle.net/gqhxt58j/6/. As to the other issue, I am not near a computer right now (I am editing in my phone). I will look at it later. Please notify if it works.

Comment: I did check but then the whole li block is taken as a Link. So if I hover on the side of the image , then too the click proceeds. 
I overcame this using : onmouseover="this.src='./images/merchandise-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./images/merchandise.png'"
Thanks for the help :)

I have another issue regarding the Font Face -> Custom Font Face for the footer. In IE, the Custom font face is not rendered -> 
Here's the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517666/custom-font-is-not-displaying-in-ie
Help me with this. Thanks