# @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

[This exception occurs in here.](http://itmcup-stg.azurewebsites.net/) You can reproduce it in IE11. So far I have not found the cause of the issue. Any ideas why this is being caused?

[image]

> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check.
>   Permission must be Installable. File:
>   53d9eae5-63b4-48d7-a5b8-3419455028bb.ttf

The web site is running on Azure Websites platform and is using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: I have the same error in IE11; but if i compare the look in IE11 and in Firefox 31 the fonts look identical. If i look at  the dev tools the css attribute  `font-family` is set to the right font. Does anyone know if the font that is rendered is the `@font-face` from the `*.ttf`file that could not be installed? In other words could it be that despite the error `CSS3114` the desired font is loaded and displayed?

Comment: Based on @NathanOliver's suggestion, I'm posting a comment instead of an answer. If you have a need to convert the font in the future, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34209206/904344

Comment: Use a chrome addon like WhatFont to verify what font is actually being used

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fixed by adding

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

under

```
 <system.webServer>
```

in web.config.

Edit:

to prevent any problems with consequent releases I recommend doing this:

```
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Could you add information if the rendering of the displayed page / element was rendered different before you applied the fix?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree if I can remember correctly I didn't spot any change.

Comment: What could be equivalent NodeJS solution?

Comment: sorry i put the code in web.config but it's not work :(

Comment: In IIS, try setting the mime type as following: fileExtension=.woff" mimeType=application/x-font-woff and similarly for .ttf

Comment: Working Fine :)

Answer (score 31):

sibaspage answer pointed me into the right direction. But I still see the error message in IE11. For me it worked using the following syntax:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Font-Name';
   src: url('../fonts/Font-Name.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/Font-Name.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: @jakub How is it the same? actually the one above is wrong, you can't set the "src" multiple times

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For me, the embedded-opentype format was missing, adding this resolved the problem.

Comment: For me it was, that the .otf -File was loaded before the .eot?#iefix -File. Reversing the loading order in the CSS worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

Another solution can be change the **Font embeddability** property file. Right click and see **Details** tab:

[image]

If this property does not appear, you can use [this service](https://www.andrebacklund.com/fontfixer.html) to add it. It only works for `.ttf` font files. But I guess there are some other services to change other font file extensions.

Comment: This solution for for me, additional i use this converter because my font was in .otf  https://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf

Comment: What is the purpose of this embeddability if you can so easily change it?

Answer (score 3):

For documentation or future visitors: In my case I was experimenting this issue with **IE11** and **.otf** fonts, if this is your case read this [Can I use case](https://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf). Basically what it says is that **IE11 doesn't support some .ttf and .otf** fonts.

The best solution I found was to **convert the .otf font to .woff** and add the code on Jakub Holovsky's response with a small change.

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
    src: url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Notice **src: local('☺'),**

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and found this article: https://creativemarket.com/blog/the-missing-guide-to-font-formats.
You can just add the relevant fonts to your font-face.

Answer (score -4):

IE not supports .ttf just use .eot font files

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font-Name';
  src: url('../fonts/Font-Name.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  src: url('../fonts/Font-Name.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```