# MIME Type Issue In IE in umbraco 7.4.3

Tags: internet-explorer, umbraco

I am getting error:

> @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable." in IE.

For resolving this I am adding the **MIME type** in **web config**. But the issue is still there.

Its working fine in other browser(**Chrome,Mozilla**). Using Umbraco version (**Umbraco 7.4.3**).

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK4xC.png)

Comment: Can you share your font registration styles?

Comment: this is my font registration style "ProximaNova-Regular.eot" , but         when i add font style sheet like "src: url('../ProximaNova-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); " then error is removed but font style is still  diffrent

Comment: And what mime type you're assigning in the web.config? Please share the whole mappings and whole block of font registration in CSS.

Comment: in web config file  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-otf" />

Comment: Try with: <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" /> or following this gist: https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/478e133b4f96a93e17bc <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype" />

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

[@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338479/font-face-failed-opentype-embedding-permission-check-permission-must-be-instal)