# HTML/CSS: Originally had TTF issues when loading site on IE but since fixing, seeing these errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I have fonts installed like this on my site:

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src:  url('/fonts/Avenir-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('/fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
     }
```

However, when I try to run it from Internet Explorer, the site won't open and these errorrs appear in console:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
Avenir-Book.eot
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
Avenir-Book.ttf
```

Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong as I thought the `eot` file resolves IE issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338479/font-face-failed-opentype-embedding-permission-check-permission-must-be-instal)

Comment: @Robbeoli this was the question I originally referenced in my solution.  I am using the solution with EOT's as directed there

Comment: Have you tried the accepted solution?

Comment: @Robbeoli really?  I said "I am using the solution with EOT's as directed there"

Comment: Easy there, herky. That solution is not the accepted solution. By the vote count it seems like it should work, though. What I asked you, is if you tried the solution actually accepted by the OP from the question.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3114 can be resolved by adding the following fixes under `<system.webServer>` in web.config:

```
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

CSS3111 could be caused by Windows 10 feature called **Entrusted Font Blocking**. You can disable it using group policy or using registry editor. For further information and detailed steps, please check [this article](https://medium.com/@zikaitoh/css3111-and-css3114-issue-640e7d5e9163).