# Embedded fonts doesn't work on IE

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, font-face

Why my embeded fonts does not work for IE...

Here is my CSS code:

```
body{}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'JSeshFont';
  src: url('fonts/JSeshFont.eot'); /* IE */
  src: url('fonts/JSeshFont.eot?#iefix'); /* IE */
  src: local('JSeshFont'), url('fonts/JSeshFont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* others */
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda';
  src: url('fonts/JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda.eot'); /* IE */
  src: url('fonts/JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda.eot?#iefix'); /* IE */
  src: local('Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Kasheeda'), url('fonts/JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda.ttf') format('truetype'); /* others */
}
```

here is my Asp.net C# code:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo/style.css" />
    </head>
<body>
   ...
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="بلا بلا بلا" Font-Names="JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="text2" runat="server" Font-Size="Large">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names="JSeshFont" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" Height="200">
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200" Width="300" Font-Names="JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200" Width="300" Font-Names="JSeshFont" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:TextBox>
...
</body>
</html>
```

here are screenshots:

http://i.imgur.com/9OZ2nxD.png

http://i.imgur.com/oVgMJUs.png

EDIT:
I'm dropping support for IE, cause IE does not support UTF-32 in any ways. (even my phone supports UTF-32....)

Comment: here is the link to the page: http://liepu-translator.org/demo/utf32embedfont/

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587956/make-adobe-fonts-work-with-css3-font-face-in-ie9

Comment: for reference, generally useful to include error messages in questions: `CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.`

Comment: @TZHX, umm, what? how to include that one?

I'm quite a noob for asp.net...

Comment: @TZHX , but I had included the "EOT" font cause of IE lack of support of "TTF"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution with the embedcode of fontsquirrel. I don't know, what your "src: local" is good for - I've never seen it before.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'JSeshFont';
src: url('fonts/JSeshFont.eot'); /* IE */
src: url('fonts/JSeshFont.eot?#iefix'), format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/JSeshFont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/JSeshFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/JSeshFont.svg#JSeshFont') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

If you don't have the complete fonts (woff etc.) you can generate them with the [FontSquirrel Webfont-Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Comment: Yeap - worked... But now the IE has the issues with UTF-32 :D

Comment: here is my web config:

<code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-32"?>
...
</code>

Comment: I never worked with UTF-32 so I can give you no hint on that one, sorry

Comment: Do you know how to show the message to each and every user of IE (every version)

Comment: P.S. your sullution did not worked, cause it showed me correct only cause I had font installed

CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.

Comment: Well, I decided already to drop the support for IE. And the reason is that that I can't ask user to convert their OTF/TTF font to EOT (while they are adding language that requires special font for currect rendering of text) only cause of 1% of IE users...