# Site Isn't Displaying Correctly In Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a website that works correctly on Chrome, Edge, and Firefox, but shows a number of errors in Internet Explorer 11. The @font-face isn't working correctly, and the "main" section of my site isn't centered like it should be. In IE, it's aligned to the left side of the page. I'm not sure what's causing these errors, as I've run both my HTML and CSS code through validators without any real issues.

http://jordanwebdesign.x10host.com/itops/

Comment: Check the answers here for the font problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587956/make-adobe-fonts-work-with-css3-font-face-in-ie9/29580508#29580508.  
The alignment issue I guess it's because `<main>` tag is not supported in IE 11 and before (not sure though). Try changing the `<main>` tag with a div and apply the same css rules to see whats happens

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears that just adding display: block to the html5 tags fixed my issue. I'll be working on the fonts in the meantime.