# Why is my @font-face broken in ie9 only?

Tags: css, stylesheet, cross-browser

I'm in the ie testing phase of a site build and I cannot get the fonts to work in ie9.  The strange part is that they work just fine in ie7 & ie8 AND in compatibility mode.  Perhaps even stranger is the fact that the demo files work just fine.  I realize this suggests I might have the plumbing messed up, but I can't find the issue anywhere.

I'm wondering if something is breaking all of the fonts in ie9 for this site -- they all look like 'times new roman' to me.

**EDIT**: updated the code below.  Still experiencing the issue.

Below is some relevant info and sample code for one of the fonts in question.  There are 5 fonts in total, and they are all set up this exact way and experiencing the same problem.

Testing Site:  http://dev.citylightphilly.com

**File structure:** all fonts & stylesheet.css in /wp-content/themes/my_theme/fonts/

HTML (in header.php)

```
<!-- @Font-Face Webfonts --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?  >/fonts/stylesheet.css" />
<!-- CSS : implied media="all" -->
    <?php versioned_stylesheet($GLOBALS["TEMPLATE_RELATIVE_URL"]."style.css?v=2") ?>
```

CSS (/fonts/stylesheet.css)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'NovecentowideBold';
src: url('Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.svg#NovecentowideBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

CSS (style.css)

```
h3, h4, h5, h6, nav {
  font-family: 'NovecentowideBold', 'Myriad Headline', Tahoma, Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This is not a wordpress question, it is a CSS question.

Comment: Having CSS problems with a WP-powered site does not make it a WP question. Migrating to Stack Overflow where this will be on-topic and will get some quality answers.

Comment: NovecentowideMedium ≠ Novecentowide-Medium

Comment: Good catch - actually a typo in the code above but not in my css file - I must have made the mistake when I was copying it over.  Fixed it in the edit.  The issue is actually happening with all the @ fonts on the site.  I'm going to dig into the F12 console and see if I can come up with anything.  In the mean time I'll update the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be the code in the CSS found in

http://dev.citylightphilly.com/wp-content/themes/citylight2/style.css

Try removing this section:

```
body, p, li { 
  font-family: ;
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: thanks font squirrel - I'll look into this later this evening when I have some time.  I appreciate the input.. I didn't realize I had an empty element there.

Comment: Awesome. Sometimes the problems are sneaky. Actually figured this out with the web inspector in Safari. :-p

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "actuall font name";
    src:url( "http://localhost//fonts/fontname.TTF ");
}
```

src url should be full with domain.

Comment: I actually did some reading up on this issue - and I think ie9 actually blocks cross-domain font requests.  See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font

Comment: this work fine for me, maybe you are checking this with ie9 compatibility view, go in f12 developer tools and check by changing Browser Mode...

Comment: nope believe it or not the @font-face actually works in compatibility mode, but not in regular