# IE9 @font-face encountered unknown error

Tags: internet-explorer, css, font-face

I'm having an issue with @font-face on IE9 (windows 7). IE 8 on XP and all browsers on mac give me no probs. Just IE9.

I'm embedding my font like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'wendy_lpregular';
    src: url('../fonts/wendylpstd-medium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/wendylpstd-medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/wendylpstd-medium.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/wendylpstd-medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/wendylpstd-medium.svg#wendy_lpregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It doesn't render the font and gives me the following error in the console:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
wendylpstd-medium.eot
```

I have another font which I am embedding - and it is displaying correctly. What could be causing the ever fantastic IE9 to be crying over this?

Comment: Did you convert these fonts yourself?

Comment: Yes, through font-squirrel

Comment: Have you attempted any other font-converters?

Comment: I tried convertfonts dot com . The only other I could find was fontface.codeandmore dot com and that is a paid service

Comment: Alright. This seems to be a [somewhat common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705327/font-face-ie-problems). Have a look there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error . Also, take a look at search result : https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&hl=fr&newwindow=1&q=CSS3111%3A+%40font-face+encountered+unknown+error.+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

> And now to our main highlight - the "CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error". This error is very ambiguous. If you have a look at MSDN again, you'll see its description says: "An unknown problem was encountered with the "Web Open Font Format (WOFF)", and "Embedded OpenType font (EOT)" of the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) font". "Unknown Problem" doesn't sound too good to me - how am I supposed to solve an unknown problem? Fortunately we're given a hint here. It says: "Check source of the fonts". Indeed, CSS3111 is usually caused by an issue with the font's binary source. One of the popular online TTF to EOT converters for example produces EOT files with a NAME table that doesn't comply to the Microsoft standards, which results in EOT fonts that never load in IE and produce the CSS3111 error. So, when you experience a CSS3111, it is always good to try using a different TTF to EOT converter or font face generator.

Source: http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/16/how-to-embed-webfonts-properly-and-how-to-solve-the-ambiguous-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error/

Comment: I did just like you : googled '**CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.**' and .. came to same conclusion than you.

Comment: yeah that is a right approach always search for the error number. good work.

Comment: Yoda, take a look at this : https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&hl=fr&newwindow=1&q=CSS3111%3A+%40font-face+encountered+unknown+error.+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your font to base64.

1. Use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/) to convert your `woff` font file to base 64.
2. Use the output from step 1 in your CSS file like this:

   ```
   src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, [base 64 value from step 1 without brackets] ) format('woff');
   ```

The final result will look something like this, where `your base64` is the value from step 1:
[image: WebFont include example]

Good luck!

Comment: Although it looks bizarre it does actually work, although unfortunately it then stopped the font from working in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @SharpC never checked, but I'm guessing leaving `woff` url before, or after `base64` solution could work.

Comment: Seems that it was a rogue `.eot` font that was causing a Firefox issue - removed that and now works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use a **simple line** to define font-face in your css, and use **absolue urls**, for exemple

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'wendy_lpregular';
    src:url('your-web.com/fonts/wendylpstd-medium.eot');
    src:url('your-web.com/fonts/wendylpstd-medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('your-web.com/fonts/wendylpstd-medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('your-web.com/fonts/wendylpstd-medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('your-web.com/fonts/wendylpstd-medium.svg#GothamRM') format('svg')
}
```

Check if you can open in IE the file (your-web.com/fonts/wendylpstd-medium.woff), If you recive error 404 go to IIS, double-click the "MIME Types" configuration option while having IIS root node selected in the left panel and click "Add..." link in the Actions panel on the right. This will bring up the following dialog. Add **.woff** file extension and specify "**application/x-font-woff**" as the corresponding MIME type

I use this instrucctions in this site ([Robòtica educativa](http://www.roboticaeducativa.cat)), I convert my original .ttf font on (http://www.font2web.com/)