# Why are some images in IE not showing after second page load?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, css

I'm working on a [new site](http://arcon.stiengenterprises.com/vare-prosjekter/) and for some reason, IE (surprise) is not showing some images after the initial page load.

It looks fine (most of the time) when the page loads for the first time, but hit F5 and most pictures are not loaded / showing (or if it is, hit F5 again).

I'm using [Isotope masonry](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for the images, but I don't see how that will effect how images are shown in IE.

[image]

Code for a image:

```
<div class="photo arealplanlegging industri  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
  <img alt="vaskeriet1" class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" src="http://arcon.stiengenterprises.com/files/2013/07/vaskeriet1-570x633.jpg">
  <a href="http://arcon.stiengenterprises.com/prosjekter/vaskeriet/" class="mask">
     <div class="container">
        <small>Arealplanlegging</small><small>Industri</small>
        <h3>Vaskeriet</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="more">+</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help appreciated.

Comment: imporvement: center the descrition of the images with the red dashed border :D

Comment: Sorry @MichaelUnterthurner, don't get what you mean. But any improvements greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Code? Where is your code? Please post an example **here**.

Comment: 9 images 9 images 9 images... IE version 9.0 on Win7 sp1  (What version of IE/OS are you on?)

Comment: I'm getting font-face errors in IE10 (Win7 SP1) which may be halting the rest of the page load - http://pastebin.com/SqtQ13q0 | Edit: Just check the network tab too, anything loading after the fonts is being aborted

Comment: @JamieTaylor I think you're right. Well spotted! I removed the Google font import and now it seems the pictures are loading on every page refresh. Care to put this as an answer?

Comment: If you are on this site http://arcon.stiengenterprises.com/prosjekter/ottoe-moe/ and you are decrease the size of the browser the details div isn't in the middle like the image

Comment: @Steven There, glad I could help, just a shame it's such a vague error on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Capturing a log file with Fiddler may help reveal the problem. "Aborted" image downloads in IE typically indicate that a navigation occurred or the pre-parser was forced to restart. This isn't typically a problem in IE9, but did you properly specify the document mode or use a doctype html declaration at the top?

Comment: Hi Eric. Yes, the document type should be ok. You can see yourself on the page. Fiddler looks like a handy tool. Kind of reminds me of Firebug. I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 2):

My Console is showing errors on IE10, Windows 7 SP1

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
zLhfkPOm_5ykmdm-wXaiuw.eot
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
2HG_tEPiQ4Z6795cGfdivPY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot
```

I'd suggest looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974104/ie9-font-face-encountered-unknown-error) for more information on that error. It might make sense to use a service like [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to convert the font files yourself. I've personally never had issues with them so far!

Comment: Hmm.... Added fonts as per suggestions. Removes error, but still one picture will not load...

Comment: The console is still reporting "<aborted>" for some of the images. I don't know enough about how IE works to help sorry, A quick google doesn't bring back much on aborted images in IE or anything related to cloudflare :(

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I added the old code back since I have to work with it a bit alter. That's why I still get the `@font-face` problem.