# Serving hosted EOT font for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, webfonts

When I try to use @font-face for an EOT font for IE, it doesn't work when the font is hosted somewhere else. It only works when it's local, in the web application.

This doesn't work:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'AvantGardeMdBTMedium';    
    src: url('http://myhost.com/fonts/fontname.eot')
}
```

This works:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGardeNormal;
    src: url('fontname.eot');
}
```

Is it possible to use a font hosted, through a full http address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to host your fonts on a different domain, but you're going to have to deal with any cross-origin policy issues if they arise. Check your Developer Tools in IE (hit F12 in IE8 or IE9) and look at the console to find any errors (cross-origin policy errors will be displayed there). For more details about correcting the cross-origin policy headers, see [IE9 blocks download of cross-origin web font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font).