# IE10: @font-face doesn't work

Tags: css, html, fonts, internet-explorer-10

I have trouble to make those font-face working on IE10.Windows 8 (though it works fine on safari).

Any idea?

```
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed Light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Condensed Light'), local('OpenSans-CondensedLight'), url(rsc/fonts/opensanscondensedlight.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Open Sans Condensed Bold'), local('OpenSans-CondensedBold'), url(rsc/fonts/opensanscondensedbold.ttf) format('truetype');
}
</style>
```

[UPDATE 1]

Here is the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/f3hduskv/

[UPDATE 2]

Got a 404 on the ttf file, I don't get it. The URL is okay. One thing though: type is shown a text/html. The mime type on IIS for rtf is known.

[image]

Comment: This issue seems to be an IE10 font DRM issue.  Similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744026/font-face-not-displaying-correctly-in-ie

Comment: Answer is contained right there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744026/font-face-not-displaying-correctly-in-ie as pointed to by @Richard Edwards

Answer (score 0):

Are font downloads disabled in IE10? It's in Internet Explorer's Settings: Security Settings-Internet Zone > Downloads > Font Download. Options are Enabled, Disabled and Prompt. If disabled you get nothing.

Comment: I already checked this: it's enabled. (I provided a jsFiddle)

Comment: Are you seeing any error in the developer console (F12)? Also do you see the file download attempt in the Network tab?

Comment: You're right I got a 404 but I really don't know why. I put the relevant screen shot as an update to the question @Richard Edwards

Comment: But… if you run it from the fiddle (no 404) and the font is not OK.

Comment: I'm getting '@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable'. I think I read that IE10 requires DRM info for ttf. Check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744026/font-face-not-displaying-correctly-in-ie

Comment: This led me to the solution. You should post the answer.