# metroUI css displaying icons as control characters

Tags: html, css, utf-8

I'm using [Metro UI CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/), but icons are shown as control characters. 
I've added charset=utf-8" to head section and added AddDefaultCharset utf-8 to httpd.conf. Still the problem persist.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out I forgot to copy the font files to the fonts directory.
`metro-bootstrap.css` references the fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iconFont';
  src: url('../fonts/iconFont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/iconFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/iconFont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/iconFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/iconFont.svg#iconFont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

So they need to be put in the appropriate directory relative to `metro-bootstrap.css`. If you download `Metro-UI-CSS-master.zip`, the fonts can be found in the `fonts` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Locate your Font directory and allow permission. (*.eot; *.woff;  *.ttf; *.svg).  And take note of the location.
2. Edit your metro-icons.css, and put the correct path of the font directory.
   (I use the browser inspection to check my path is correct)
3. Refresh your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<!DOCTYPE html>` as your doctype, I suggest you to try this.

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

*instead of*

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Do you have a live link for this issue? Or can you provide your code and create a jsFiddle for it?

Comment: Page is on intranet so i can't share the link. please try the jsfiddle link above

Answer (score 0):

You need both the external set of css (metro-bootstrap.css) as well as class="metro"...
Here's a working copy:
http://jsfiddle.net/67T6c/

```
<link href="css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="metro">
<i class="icon-home"></i>
</div>
```

also note that this works in Chrome. However, in IE, you may be limited by the wonderful cross-origin-web-font block. See THIS for details on that: [IE9 blocks download of cross-origin web font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font)

Answer (score 0):

You must also be sure that your web server **does not block** files download with the extensions required for the font.
These are: **eot; ttf; woff; svg**

I had the same problem and I could not in any way solve the problem of the icons. I later discovered that the problem was due to the web server used for development, **Delphi DataSnap stand-alone mode**, because of filtering these extensions so these files where not returned to the browser.

For Delphi DataSnap the solution is:

- Go to `WebModuleUnit`
- Select `WebFileDispatcher1`
- Dbl-click on `WebFileExtensions` property and add the file extensions required.