# font-face wordpress - IE issue

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face, webfonts

I have the website, based on wordpress, which uses my own theme. The problem is that when I open site in the IE, in the console I receive error CSS3117 about "cross-origin request".

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Centurygothic';
  src: url('fonts/Centurygothic.eot');
  src: url('fonts/Centurygothic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/Centurygothic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/Centurygothic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/Centurygothic.svg#centurygothic') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Fonts are in the same directory as styles etc, morever when I open that font by direct url, font is found properly. So it is strange that cross-domain problem appears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll find the answer in [this prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font) on cross-origin web fonts and IE.