# Font Fact Issue in IE11

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I'm having a strange issue loading my font faces on my new website. It seems that all but one font-face is displaying correctly.

The font in question on my website is deibi. It loads just fine on all other browsers, just not IE11 or any other version of IE for that matter.

Here is the link for comparison.

http://hemgroup.com/demoserver/jardin/

I'm done a few searches and tried a few different things but all not no avail it seems.

Any tips or suggestions on where to look would be awesome. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, looks like out server was having issues. Should load now.

Comment: Sure do, I took a SS in IE 11 and FF for comparison.

Comment: http://hemgroup.com/demoserver/jardin/jardin-ss.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to be able to replicate the problem but i did see some errors in IE when loading the page.

I was receiving this error message when loading your page:

```
CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.
File: deibi-webfont.eot

CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.
File: economica-regular-otf-webfont.eot
```

IE has very strict rules on loading fonts and font permissions and i think that these may not be setup right. The headers may also not be being called in correctly and therefore may be causing an error on your side.

Have a quick read up on this error which i think is what the problem is: [IE9 blocks download of cross-origin web font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font)