# Adding custom font to asp.net application

Tags: html, css, asp.net, font-face

I have never used a custom font before and have been trying to add it into my application. I have downloaded this font onto my computer and have made a separate file called 'Font' and in that i have put the font file.

I went into my CSS and have wrote this code:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'Open Sans';
src: url('../Font/OpenSans-Light.ttf');
}
```

The font isn't working at all and I'm wondering why it is not working?

Any ideas?

I am applying it to different sections, I should of said:

```
.title {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size: 25px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #52a3cc;
text-align: center;
}
```

I get this error message in IE Developer Tools:

```
"@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable."
```

Comment: [This page](http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/) describes how to add the MIME type to IIS.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font help?

Comment: I have embedded fonts and can't get away with just TTF fonts, because not all browsers support all formats. I use woff, eot, ttf and svg

Answer (score 1):

You code should work if you can download `http://www.yoursite.com/CorrectPath/OpenSans-Light.ttf` in a browser.

If you cannot download it, you need to add at MIME types like SethG suggested.

### Other thought

Open Sans is available via [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts), so you do not have to host it by yourself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with this in the past. If you're using IIS Express to test this, you might have issues. For some reason, when IIS doesn't have a MIME type with which to serve content, it won't serve it. Make sure that whatever version of IIS you're using, be it IIS Express or IIS, has a MIME type for .ttf files.

Comment: When I have added the font-face, the font doesn't even work on my local machine now.