# How to make your own fonts work

Tags: javascript, font-face, glyphicons, custom-font

I have copied a font file and updated one of the icons with my own - it works fine in Chrome, however IE is comming with this error:

> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check.
>   Permission must be Installable

Can anybody tell me what I need to do with my font file inorder to avoid this issue

Comment: You need a '.eot' font to get @font-face working on IE

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator