# Issue with $http in IE 9 using Angular

Tags: angularjs, http

I am working on a sample application using angular js. I am a newbie , so please bear with me

**I have the following code in my controllers.js :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.artists = data;
        $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
    });
}]);
```

Here , i am using http.get to load json data into application from a text file as shown above.

I am using IE 9 and was allowed to use only that , not any browser.

When i execute the above code, i am encountering an error as stated below :

**CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted**

I am not sure what is a **cross-origin** request . I am wondering why a simple http get requested is  getting failed.

**Here are my queries :**

1. What is a cross origin request? An example would be great
2. How this holds w.r.t  my example above ?
3. What is the remedy/solution/alternative for this ?

Comment: seems like your question is related to IE 9 and font-face: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font Cross origin means that you are on domianA.com and trying to access resources on domainB.com

Answer (score -1):

Try defining a var outside the controller:

```
this.artists = {};
```

And then, inside the controller:

```
this.artists = data;
```

So the page can access that var. Otherside you can only access it inside the controller.

Comment: Can you pleease explain how does your solution relate to Cross origin request ?

Comment: -1 there is no font face import in a json request. This answer does nothing to solve OP issue